# Unable to change font size using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Being new to d3.js, I am trying to write a simple code to compute font-sizes for paragraphs from an array. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    d3.select('body')
      .selectAll('p')
      .data([5,10])
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>para 1</p>
<p>para 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like a very simple thing to do but for some reason isn't working. Any help as to where I am going wrong would really help.

Comment: it wors fine, add to your code `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`

Comment: Thanks @MindaugasVečkys . . I understood where I was going wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening because when the script is getting executed, till that time the `<P>` elements haven't been created.So just include the Script at the end of the page and it should work fine.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/E89M5/)

The Code will be something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>para 1</p>
<p>para 2</p>
</body>

<script>
    d3.select('body')
      .selectAll('p')
      .data([5,10])
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });
</script>
</html>
```

**Method 2**

You can also write your script in the `onLoad` event so that it gets executed only after the DOM is created.

In pure JavaScript it can be done like this

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){

d3.select('body')
      .selectAll('p')
      .data([5,10])
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });

}
</script>
```

Alternately you can use jQuery (if you prefer) .Its sample code will be something like this

```
    <script>
      $(document).on('laod',funciton(){
       d3.select('body')
              .selectAll('p')
              .data([5,10])
              .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });
    });</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to generate the HTML/SVG elements directly from the data as explained in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/).

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        d3.select('body')
            .data([5,10])
          .enter().append("p")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; })
            .text("para");
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```